# Memory issue when parsing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, memory-management

The below xmlparser Code shows memory warning, i couldnt fix it for a while any clues please help me

```
if  ([elementName isEqualToString:@"page_details"])
    {
        IstructPageDetails *objIstructPageDetails = [[IstructPageDetails alloc] initwithIstructPageDetails:attributeDict];
        [m_objmuteArrOutput addObject:objIstructPageDetails];
        [objIstructPageDetails release];

    }

Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller
```

Comment: That code looks good to me (assuming `m_objmuteArrOutput` is an `NSMutableArray` of course, as its name implies).  Are you sure its **that** line causing the warning message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

initwithIstructPageDetails should be initWithIstructPageDetails:helps because the analyzer looks at the cocoa naming conventions

As the code looks good, that's the only possibility in my eyes

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  Doesn't the convention state that it starts with `init`, so why is the `with`/`With` bit important?

Comment: I assume here but I think that it does camelCase to separate words. initwith = 1 word, initWith = 2 words

Comment: Yeah you could be right.  In fact I cannot see what other explanation is possible.